# Search content in JSON array using index name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON array `[{"id":38,"label":"def"},{"id":10,"label":"abc"}]`

I need to get result array as `{"id":38,"label":"def"}` when enter a keyword "d" or "e" of "f" like that.

I tried using jQuery to do this:

```
var jsonArrr =[{"id":38,"label":"def"},{"id":10,"label":"abc"}];

var matchMe = new RegExp('^' + 'e', 'i');
    var matches = [];
        for (var i in jsonArrr) {
            if (jsonArrr[i].label.search(matchMe) > -1 ) {
                    matches.push( {'id': i, 'label': jsonArrr[i].label} );
            }
        }

content = '';
for (var i in matches) { 
                console.log(matches[i].label);
                }
```

But this code outputs

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in place of search you can use match function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) (to find value in string), like this

```js
var data = [{"id":38,"label":"def"}, {"id":10,"label":"abc"}, {"id":38,"label":"ABC"}];

function filter(data, keyword) {
  return data.filter(function (el) {
    return el.label.indexOf(keyword) >= 0;
  })
} 

function filterCaseInsensitive(data, keyword) {
  return data.filter(function (el) {
    return new RegExp(keyword, 'i').test(el.label);
  })
}

$('#keyword').on('keyup', function () {
  $('#result').html( JSON.stringify(filter(data, this.value)) );
  $('#resultCaseInsensitive').html( JSON.stringify(filterCaseInsensitive(data, this.value)) );  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="keyword" type="text">
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="resultCaseInsensitive"></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to check case insensitive.. ie get same result when "a" or "A" is pressed??

Comment: @V P could you give me example what do you want you get as result ?

Comment: ie ,when enter a keyword "d"  od "D" shows the same result.
CaseInsensitive searching/Filtering..

Comment: @V P have you tried second function `filterCaseInsensitive` ? when you enter a or A you will get the same result in second example

Answer (score 1):

you can also do like this

```
jsonArrr.filter(function(item) { return new RegExp('.*'+keyword+'.*').test(item.label); })
```

but i suggest to use indexOf in you case